# How to append v-on:click event to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Excuse me, I want to append vue.js event and html to html element.

But, Append is not can't using vue.js event(OpenTabDropdown)
(ps:I use jquery append function)

Vue.js

```
const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        methods:{
            Append(){
                var moreArray = new Array();
                moreArray.push("<a v-on:click='OpenTabDropdown($event)' href='javascript:;'><i class='fa fa-angle-double-down none' aria-hidden='true'></i> </a>");
                $('.show_wrap').append(moreArray);
            },
            OpenTabDropdown(event){
               $(event.target).find('.fa-angle-double-down').toggleClass('none');
            }
        },
});
```

Html

```
<div ip="app">
<div class="show_wrap">
</div>
</div>
```

like this top code.

I want moreArray append to div(show_wrap).

but OpenTabDropdown is not any response.

How can I do , Please Help me , Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly.  i want to append vue.js event to html. then can OpenTabDropdown this function.

Comment: Why dont you `<div class="show_wrap" @click="function">` ? and then when you click on this div you can add to something to array

Comment: This is definitely not how you should be using Vue. Absolutely do not modify the DOM directly! Instead, you should be modifying data fields in order to trigger any necessary DOM changes. Please read through the Vue.js documentation in order to better understand how Vue works and how best to utilize its own built-in functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late reply @CaShiS It should be my question is weird,I need to redesign my logic.. thanks your reply!

Comment: @B.Fleming thanks! I re-read a document, I found how I did,just need to throw the value of the data, do not need to do append action!  thanks your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you want to append, but here is something similar.

- You can add/remove your html parts via `v-if`
- You can store your data in $data
- You can toggle your html parts with your method.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function(){
    return {
     isDropdownEnabled: false,
     yourData: [
      {name: 'John'},
      {name: 'Sarah'}
     ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleDropdown(event){
       this.$set(this.$data, 'isDropdownEnabled', !this.isDropdownEnabled)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="my-data" v-if="isDropdownEnabled">
    <div v-for="data in yourData">{{data.name}}</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <a @click.prevent="toggleDropdown" href="">
    <i class='fa fa-angle-double-down none' aria-hidden='true'></i>
    toggle dropdown
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I refer to your method, found a similar way to solve the problem！ thanks !